# Verify the expected scope of an autowired bean?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose there is a bean defined as:

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class Person {
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and a rest controller such as:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private Person person;

    @RequestMapping("/age/{newAge}")
    public String age(@PathVariable("age") int newAge) {
        int previousAge = person.getAge();
        person.setAge(newAge);
        return previousAge + ":" + newAge;
    }
}
```

As expected, based on the **configuration in Person**, `person` within the controller  is defined for each session.

Later, somebody decides to change `Person` to @RequestScope.  Now the controller's behavior is broken.

Is there a way to verify the expected scope of `person`?

Something like @autowired(requiredScope="session")?

Comment: How is the controller's behavior broken? What would you have it do?

Comment: @shmosel - if Person is changed to RequestScope then there's a new person on each request instead of re-using the existing person from the session.

Comment: I understand. But that's not a bug in the controller, it's a problem with the scope. Again, what would your proposed annotation actually do?

Comment: I supposed it would need to be a start up exception, to verify the scope configuration of Person matches the expected scope of the controller.

Comment: stupid question: why not add a comment. `Don't change this line to request scope!. It will break the Person controller`. problem solved. I honestly don't think you want to create some sort of unit test to verify that you have the desired annotation on your class

Comment: Who will guard the guards?

Comment: It's a silly example - I was more concerned about 3rd party jars which provide their own @Configuration which might change scope on different versions.